# Android: Passing data from a table to another

Tags: android

This is the scenario of my system:
1. Register user then user will go to registerUser database (made in DBAdapter)
2. If add user is clicked, it will show listview of registered user (I am trying to pass the names from DBAdapter to another table{from DBAdapter2}

Error happens when I open the activity.

CurrentUsers.java

```
        package com.example.istronggyminstructor;

        import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.PopupWindow;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

        public class CurrentUsers extends Activity {
            private Button register;
            private Button adduser;
            EditText getusertext, getpass, getweight, textdisp;
            DBAdapter myDB;
            DBAdapter2 myDB2;
            View popupview,popupview2;


            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_current_users);
                register = (Button)findViewById(R.id.regbut);
                adduser = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addbut);
                register.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        LayoutInflater inflator=(LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                        popupview=inflator.inflate(R.layout.popup, null);
                        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupview, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupview, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                        popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
                        popupWindow.update();
                        Button dismissbtn = (Button)popupview.findViewById(R.id.close);
                        dismissbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                                popupWindow.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(register, 50, -30);
                    }
                });
                openDB();
                //Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new forceclose(this));
                ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listme);
                openDB2();
                ArrayList<String> data = myDB2.geData(); 
                closeDB2();
                lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data));
            }

            public void openDB(){
                myDB = new DBAdapter(this);
                myDB.open();
            }

            public void openDB2(){
                myDB2 = new DBAdapter2(this);
                myDB2.open();
            }
            private void closeDB() {
                myDB.close();
            }
            public void closeDB2(){
                myDB2.close();
            }
            private void displayText(String message) {
                openDB();
                //TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.);
                //textView.setText(message);
            }

            public void registerUser(View v) {
                openDB();
                EditText username = (EditText)popupview.findViewById(R.id.usertext);
                EditText password = (EditText)popupview.findViewById(R.id.passwordtext);
                EditText weight = (EditText)popupview.findViewById(R.id.weight);
                String getUsername = username.getText().toString();
                String getPassword = password.getText().toString();
                int getWeight = Integer.parseInt(weight.getText().toString());
                long newId = myDB.insertRow(getUsername, getPassword, getWeight);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registering...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Cursor cursor = myDB.getRow(newId);
            }

            public void onClick_ClearAll(View v) {
                openDB();
                myDB.deleteAll();
            }

            public void onClick_DisplayRecords(View v) {
                openDB(); 
                Cursor cursor = myDB.getAllRows();
                displayRecordSet(cursor);
            }


                private void displayRecordSet(Cursor cursor) {
                    String message = "";
                    openDB();
                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {

                            int id = cursor.getInt(DBAdapter.COL_ROWID);
                            String name = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_NAME);
                            String password = cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_PASSWORD);
                            int weight = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(DBAdapter.COL_WEIGHT));


                            message += "Name=" + name +
                                       "Weight " + weight
                                       +"\n";
                        } while(cursor.moveToNext());
                    }
                    cursor.close();

                    displayText(message);
                }
                public void onClick_addUser(View v){
                    LayoutInflater inflator=(LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    popupview2=inflator.inflate(R.layout.popup2, null);
                    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupview2, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupview2, Gravity.CENTER, 0, -10);
                    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
                    popupWindow.update();
                    Button dismissbtn = (Button)popupview2.findViewById(R.id.close2);
                    dismissbtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View arg0) {
                            popupWindow.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(register, 50, -30);
                    myDB2.getUser();

        }




            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.current_users, menu);
                return true;
            }

        }
```

XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.16" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="220dp"
            android:text="@string/title_activity_current_users"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="98dp"
            android:text="@string/name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="200dp"
            android:paddingTop="98dp"
            android:text="@string/timein" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="400dp"
            android:paddingTop="98dp"
            android:text="@string/score" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="540dp"
            android:paddingTop="98dp"
            android:text="@string/done" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/regbut"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/register" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/addbut"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="505dp"
            android:onClick="onClick_addUser"
            android:text="@string/adduser" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:onClick="onClick_ClearAll"
            android:text="@string/cleardb" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textdisp"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="738dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

DBAdapter.java

```
package com.example.istronggyminstructor;


import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;



public class DBAdapter {

private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;

public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "name";
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
public static final String KEY_WEIGHT = "weight";


public static final int COL_NAME = 1;
public static final int COL_PASSWORD = 2;
public static final int COL_WEIGHT = 3;


public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_USERNAME, KEY_PASSWORD, KEY_WEIGHT};

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "userDb";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "mainTable";
// Track DB version if a new version of your app changes the format.
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;   

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = 
        "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE 
        + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + KEY_USERNAME + " text not null, "
        + KEY_PASSWORD + " text not null, "
        + KEY_WEIGHT + " integer not null"
        + ");";

private final Context context;

private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

public DBAdapter open() {
    db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}


public void close() {
    myDBHelper.close();
}

// Add a new set of values to the database.
public long insertRow(String name, String password, int weight) {

    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(KEY_USERNAME, name);
    initialValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
    initialValues.put(KEY_WEIGHT, weight);

    // Insert it into the database.
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}


public boolean deleteRow(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, where, null) != 0;
}

public void deleteAll() {
    Cursor c = getAllRows();
    long rowId = c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            deleteRow(c.getLong((int) rowId));              
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    c.close();
}


public Cursor getAllRows() {
    String where = null;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                        where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}


public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                    where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}


public boolean updateRow(long rowId, String name, String password,int weight) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;


    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
    newValues.put(KEY_USERNAME, name);
    newValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
    newValues.put(KEY_WEIGHT, weight);

    // Insert it into the database.
    return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, newValues, where, null) != 0;
}




/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Private Helper Classes:
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/**
 * Private class which handles database creation and upgrading.
 * Used to handle low-level database access.
 */
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
        _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading application's database from version " + oldVersion
                + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data!");

        // Destroy old database:
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);

        // Recreate new database:
        onCreate(_db);
    }
}
}
```

DBAdapter2.java

```
package com.example.istronggyminstructor;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;



public class DBAdapter2 {

private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter2";

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final int COL_ROWID = 0;

public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "name";
public static final int COL_NAME = 1;



public static final String[] ALL_KEYS = new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_USERNAME};

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "currentUserDb";
public static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "addUserTable";
// Track DB version if a new version of your app changes the format.
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;   

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = 
        "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE 
        + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + KEY_USERNAME + " text not null, "
        + ");";

private final Context context;

private DatabaseHelper myDBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter2(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    myDBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

public DBAdapter2 open() {
    db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}


public void close() {
    myDBHelper.close();
}

// Add a new set of values to the database.
public void getUser() {
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO currentUserDb.addUserTable SELECT name FROM userDb.mainTable");

}


public Cursor getAllRows() {
    String where = null;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                        where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}


public Cursor getRow(long rowId) {
    String where = KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId;
    Cursor c =  db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, ALL_KEYS, 
                    where, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null) {
        c.moveToFirst();
    }
    return c;
}

public ArrayList<String> geData() {
    String[]columns=new String[]{ KEY_ROWID,KEY_USERNAME};
    Cursor c =db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    int iName=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_USERNAME);
    for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
        result.add(c.getString(iName));
    }
    return result;
}


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//  Private Helper Classes:
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/**
 * Private class which handles database creation and upgrading.
 * Used to handle low-level database access.
 */
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase _db) {
        _db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE_SQL);


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase _db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading application's database from version " + oldVersion
                + " to " + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data!");

        // Destroy old database:
        _db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);

        // Recreate new database:
        onCreate(_db);
    }
}
}
```

LOGCAT

```
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity   ComponentInfo{com.example.istronggyminstructor/com.example.istronggyminstructor.CurrentUsers}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table addUserTable (_id integer primary key autoincrement, name text not null, );
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234) 
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: create table addUserTable (_id integer primary key autoincrement, name text not null, );
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1663)
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1594)
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    at com.example.istronggyminstructor.DBAdapter2$DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DBAdapter2.java:116)
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:252)
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    at com.example.istronggyminstructor.DBAdapter2.open(DBAdapter2.java:51)
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    at com.example.istronggyminstructor.CurrentUsers.openDB2(CurrentUsers.java:75)
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    at com.example.istronggyminstructor.CurrentUsers.onCreate(CurrentUsers.java:62)
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-19 02:50:23.374: E/AndroidRuntime(14680):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have syntax error while compiling create table addUserTable ......

try removing the comma after 'not null' on 'DATABASE_CREATE_SQL' in your DBAdapater2 class.

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE_SQL = 
    "create table " + DATABASE_TABLE 
    + " (" + KEY_ROWID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
    + KEY_USERNAME + " text not null "
    + ");";
```

Comment: that solved it but another problem is up. Thank you btw!